# Sas process sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas, proc

I am trying to select from a SQL server table that both has dashes in the name and is greater than 32 characters.

I have tried pass through and quotes but no joy.

It's very unlikely that I could get a view produced and only have read access.

```
proc sql;
    drop table poss_gw1;
    create table poss_gw1 as ( select * from cdb.'''form_Garden_waste_service_AF-Form-59fb9946-0f6e-4cd9-‌​9b30-82fc5d96ec71'''‌​n as agg);
quit;

proc sql;
    connect to odbc(dsn=FirmstepReporting user=myname pwd=mypwd);
    Create table work.tmp_gw as select * from connection to odbc (select * from "'form_Garden_waste_service_AF-Form-59fb9946-0f6e-4cd9-9b30-‌​82fc5d96ec71'"n);
    disconnect from odbc;
quit;
```

Any one have any ideas?

Comment: Hi Andrew, welcome to SO. Please edit your question with your attempted query and some sample data of the table you are querying and from that sample the desired output. It will be a lot better to us understand and better help you with your problem.

Comment: Hi Code I have tried:

proc sql;
drop table poss_gw1;

create table poss_gw1 as (
select *
from cdb.'''form_Garden_waste_service_AF-Form-59fb9946-0f6e-4cd9-9b30-82fc5d96ec71'''n as agg);
quit;

/* Have tried with all diff combinations of quotes */

/* Also tried pass through queries - again diff variations */

proc sql; 
connect to odbc(dsn=FirmstepReporting user=myname pwd=mypwd); 
Create table work.tmp_gw as
select * from connection to odbc 
(select * from "'form_Garden_waste_service_AF-Form-59fb9946-0f6e-4cd9-9b30-82fc5d96ec71'"n); 
disconnect from odbc; 
quit;

Comment: Add it on your question, not in comments. Click on the edit button above and add your code there, add four spaces before every line so the code will be formatted.

Comment: doesn't SQL server use []'s for tables/columns/names etc?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use SQL Server syntax in the pass thru code.

```
create table work.tmp_gw as 
select * from connection to odbc 
(select * 
 from "form_Garden_waste_service_AF-Form-59fb9946-0f6e-4cd9-9b30-‌​82fc5d96ec71"
);
```

If your variable names are also not valid for SAS then you will need to change the name in the pass thru code also.

```
create table work.tmp_gw as 
select * from connection to odbc 
(select id
      , "invalid-name" as valid_name 
 from "form_Garden_waste_service_AF-Form-59fb9946-0f6e-4cd9-9b30-‌​82fc5d96ec71"
);
```